# Django - missing FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-admin

Okay, its been a while yet I can not solve or understand this problem. I also looked the other ones questions which has the same or similar title but I think this one seems different. I am not a pro in django and its admin face, but trying. So any help would be great.

I am currently trying to build an admin interface for listing the fan profiles. ( there are fans and famous users ) And I was able to list them by their `deleted post count`. ie. they post something and this can be deleted by moderators but not users theirselves. And I wrote an sql query for it.

```
sql_deleted_post_count = """
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM posts_post 
        WHERE posts_post.state = {state_deleted} AND posts_post.deleted_by_id != posts_post.user_id AND 
              posts_post.user_id = profiles_user.id
    """.format(state_deleted=Post.STATE_DELETED)
```

This seems okay in the first place. It lists the correct results for the correct users. But problem begins when I try to search a fan profile in the `search` section in the django admin panel. 
[Here you can see the search section and the correct deleted post count lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUNov.png)

When I want to search a fan profile,  here what happens :

```
ProgrammingError at /cp/profiles/fanprofile/
missing FROM-clause entry for table "profiles_user"
LINE 5:                   posts_post.user_id = profiles_user.id
                                   ^
```

but I can see that the query works fine when it comes to listing the deleted post counts.

Here is my fanprofile class from admin.py

```
class FanProfileAdmin(OSMGeoAdmin, BaseUserAdmin):
 model = FanProfile
 actions = ("send_push_notification",)
 fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('email', 'username', 'password')}),
    (_('Profile'), {'fields': ('full_name', 'avatar', 'year_of_birth', 'gender', 'language', 'about', 'location_name', "abuse_report_validity_score",)}),
    (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('receive_message', 'is_visible',  'is_profile_visible', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                   'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
    (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
 )

  add_fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'classes': ('wide',),
        'fields': ('email', 'username', 'password1', 'password2')
    }),
 )

 add_form = FanCreationForm

 list_display = ('username', 'email', 'is_profile_visible', "abuse_report_validity_score", 'is_staff', 'date_joined', 'deleted_post_count')
 readonly_fields = ("date_joined", "language", "abuse_report_validity_score", "is_visible", "is_profile_visible")

 def get_urls(self):
     return self.get_push_notification_urls() + super(FanProfileAdmin, self).get_urls()

 def has_add_permission(self, request):
     return False

 def suit_row_attributes(self, obj, request):
     if not obj.is_visible:
         return {'class': 'error'}

 def delete_model(self, request, obj):
     obj.log_action("Deactivated", log_user_id=request.user.id)

    super(FanProfileAdmin, self).delete_model(request, obj)

 def get_queryset(self, request):
     queryset = super(FanProfileAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)

     sql_deleted_post_count = """
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM posts_post 
        WHERE posts_post.state = {state_deleted} AND posts_post.deleted_by_id != posts_post.user_id AND 
              posts_post.user_id = profiles_user.id
    """.format(state_deleted=Post.STATE_DELETED)
     return queryset.annotate(total_deleted_post_count=RawSQL(sql_deleted_post_count, []))

 def deleted_post_count(self, obj):
    return obj.total_deleted_post_count

 deleted_post_count.admin_order_field = "total_deleted_post_count"
```

I don't know why this causes an issue while I try to search a fan profile instead of listing deleted post counts. 
Could you please help ?

**Edit**
I am using postgre sql.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using raw SQL at all? This is a simple query which can easily be expressed in the model query API.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I loose the ability to order by deleted_post_count. This is something I need. That's why I annotated it in the first place. By ordering I can see the users who has the most deleted post and ban them from the app if necessary